# passing date object to hibernate query

Tags: java, date, formatting

Is there anyway to specify the Date format in Java? I'm not asking about string formatting. When I inspect a date value (in debug mode) in my REST services, it looks like follows:

```
Mon Sep 01 00:00:00 IST 2014
```

When I pass this date to a hibernate query, it doesn't return me any results, event though there's valid results that satisfies the criteria. Following is my hibernate query:

```
select this_.ID as ID1_59_0_, this_.SEVERITY as SEVERITY5_59_0_, this_.EVENT as EVENT2_59_0_, this_.PROCESS_NAME   as PROCESS3_59_0_, this_.HOST_NAME as HOST6_59_0_, this_.TIME as TIME4_59_0_ 
from SYSTEM_LOG this_ 
where this_.TIME>? and this_.TIME<?
order by this_.TIME asc
```

I run this query in mySQL and pass pass the date as follows, it doesn't return any data, which I believe is what's happening in the application:

```
    select this_.ID as ID1_59_0_, this_.SEVERITY as SEVERITY5_59_0_, this_.EVENT as EVENT2_59_0_, this_.PROCESS_NAME   as PROCESS3_59_0_, this_.HOST_NAME as HOST6_59_0_, this_.TIME as TIME4_59_0_ 
from SYSTEM_LOG this_ 
where this_.TIME> 'Mon Sep 01 00:00:00 IST 2014' and this_.TIME<'Mon Sep 11 00:00:00 IST 2014'
order by this_.TIME asc;
```

But if I change the date as follows, the query returns data:

```
     select this_.ID as ID1_59_0_, this_.SEVERITY as SEVERITY5_59_0_, this_.EVENT as EVENT2_59_0_, this_.PROCESS_NAME   as PROCESS3_59_0_, this_.HOST_NAME as HOST6_59_0_, this_.TIME as TIME4_59_0_ 
from SYSTEM_LOG this_ 
where this_.TIME> '2014/9/1' and this_.TIME<'2014/9/11'
order by this_.TIME asc;
```

How do I use the correct date format? I tried doing the following, but still the date is shown in same format:

```
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date sDate = formatter.parse(startDate);
        Date eDate = formatter.parse(endDate);
```

Update:
FOllowing is the hibernate method I use to retrieve the data:

```
 public PagedDataResult getSystemLogsByDate(Date startDate, Date endDate, String sortColumn, int searchBySeverity,
                                           String searchByProcessName, String searchByHostName, String searchByDescription,
                                           int page, int pageSize) {
    String sortField = "time";
    List<Criterion> criteria = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.gt(sortField, startDate));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.lt(sortField, endDate));
    if(searchBySeverity >= 0)
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("alarmSeverities.id", searchBySeverity));
    if(!searchByProcessName.isEmpty())
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("processName", searchByProcessName));
    if(!searchByHostName.isEmpty())
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("servers.hostName", searchByHostName));
    if(!searchByDescription.isEmpty())
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("event", searchByDescription));
    return (PagedDataResult)getAllBySort(sortColumn, page, pageSize, criteria);
}
```

Comment: how is the date defined in the DB?  Are you using as PreparedStatement in your java code?  If so set the parameter using a java.sql.Date

Comment: the date is a TimeStamp

Comment: Cheers for info CHAT=2013, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that I will retrieve using TimeStamp

```
java.util.Date date = getItSomehow();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ts > ?");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
```

the method `getItSomehow` will convert your String to a Date using SimpleDateFormat.

based upon the String that you are getting from your REST system, the mask would be

```
EEE MMM HH:mm:ss yyyy Z -> Mon Sep 01 00:00:00 IST 2014
```

based upon your updated code,  try

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.gt(sortField, new Timestamp(startDate.getTime ())));
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt(sortField,  new Timestamp(endDate.getTime ())));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks now I get the date converted property to the short date format as I need. However, the hibernate query now throws an error - "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'stinga_1'". The only criteria that's valid is the two dates as I'm not setting other criteria restrictions for now.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand is you have a date as String as you have speciified and you want to use it to a select query then you need to change it to sql format date in the following way

First transform from StringDate to java.util.Date

```
public static java.util.Date transformFromStringToDate(String dateInString){
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
java.util.Date utilDate = null;
try {
   if(dateInString != null && !(dateInString.equals(""))) {
   utilDate = dateFormat.parse(dateInString);
 }
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
    return utilDate;
}
```

Then convert the java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

```
  public static java.sql.Date convertUtilDateToSqlDate(java.util.Date date){
    if(date != null && !(date.equals(""))) {
       Date sqlDate = new Date(date.getTime());
       return sqlDate;
     }
        return null;
   }
```

Finally use the java.sql.Date in you query for the PreparedStatement

If you directly have java.util.Date then skip the first step

**Edit**

if the column is a `timestamp` you need to convert the `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Timestamp` like this

```
public java.sql.Timestamp convertUtilDateToSqlTimestamp(java.util.Date date){
    if(date != null && !(date.equals(""))) {
       Timestamp sqlTimestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
       return sqlTimestamp ;
     }
        return null;
   }
public PagedDataResult getSystemLogsByDate(Date startDate, Date endDate,..) {
  java.sql.Timestamp startTimestamp = new YourClassName()
                                      .convertUtilDateToSqlTimestamp(startDate);
  java.sql.Timestamp endTimestamp =  new YourClassName()
                                      .convertUtilDateToSqlTimestamp(endDate);
...
criteria.add(Restrictions.gt(sortField, startTimestamp));
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt(sortField, endTimestamp));
...
}
```

Have this method convert the Date to sql timestamp and use the convert timestamp for querying

Comment: Unless we know how the date is stored in the DB, then any answer is just a guess.

Comment: If it is a date and you are using a PreparedStatement then you do not have to worry about format.  But if they store dates as Strings, then we also need to know.

Comment: but PreparedStatement#setDate takes in int and java.sql.Date as argument so how can we set util date to it

Comment: The OP does not mention java.util.Date at all.  I agree that your answer is probably the correct one, but until he answers some questions, we are all just guessing.

Comment: in that case yes agree with you :)

Comment: I don't use  PreparedStatement. I simply pass a util.Date object through my REST call and use it straight away in the hibernate method. But what I see is passed to the hibernate query is the date in that format given in my question, which doesnt return any data.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my DB column is timestamp. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

That's maybe because you're using `java.util.Date` instead of `java.sql.Date`. Try changing your import to `java.sql.Date` and see if it works out.

Comment: Maybe you're meaning that this should be a comment

Answer (score -1):

By default mySql uses the Swedish locale and all dates must be submitted as '2014-08-26'. Change your date formatter to SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);